# Sometimes getting sent to /admin/undefined after login

Tags: login

After logging in to the Craft admin area I sometimes(!) get routed to `/admin/undefined` instead of `/admin/dashboard`.

Anyone knows were to start looking to solve this issue?

Comment: That's... odd.  Do you have any Craft plugins installed? Does it happen across multiple browsers?

Comment: Hi Brad,
I already tried to disable and remove all plugins, but that didn't made any difference. Neighter does changing browsers. Right now I've 'solved' the issue by making a redirect in the vhost to push all undefined to dashboard.

Comment: Super-strange. Never heard of that behavior before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happened for me when I had the LastPass browser plugin version 3.3.1. Once I upgraded to 4.1.29, the issue went away.

Comment: Now that you say it, that's the same here! :)